# Velocity does not change on a rigidbody in unity3d gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject which has a rigidbody2d component.

[image]

And in my code I have the following:

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        print("Something");
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x+5, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        //MovePlayer();

    }
```

But when I run the game, `Something` is printed but the gameobject is not moving. Any idea what is my mistake?

Comment: Finally I found the problem. I should uncheck the `Apply Root Motion`, and check the `Animate Physics`

Answer (score 0):

> Finally I found the problem. I should uncheck the Apply Root Motion,
>   and check the Animate Physics

Correct, these settings from the Animate component of the GameObject your animation script is attached to will do this.

As for clarification as to why this is the case in case anyone else needs to know, root motion just applies the animation to the object itself around its body transform.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html , https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRootMotion.html